# JQuery not refreshing attribute after updating it with same value

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

```
<img th:with="imageUrl=${@myService.getImageUrl()}" th:src="${imageUrl != '' ? imageUrl : 'images/blank.jpg'}" alt="user-image" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" id="profile-img"/>
```

the URL is updated automatically on load by spring, now if you change the image (by uploading a new one) the url is still gonna be the same, but to force jquery to reload the image (I don't want to reload the whole page) I call:

```
var imgSrc = $('#profile-img').attr('src');
$('#profile-img').attr('src', imgSrc );
```

Which will be basically the same URL, I'm just changing it to force JQuery to reload the image because ieven though it's the same URL the actual content has changed in the background. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is probably cached, try using a cache buster or configure your server to tell the browser not to cache the image.

Cache buster

```
$('#profile-img').attr('src', imgSrc + '?dc='+(new Date()).getTime() );
```

Comment: thanks man this worked like a charm, i actually appended ?lastmod="1234" to the end of the url and that fixed it